# Know free memory in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7-emulator

How to know the free space in Windows Phone. I need to know the total free space, not only in IsolatedStorage

Is the "IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().AvailableFreeSpace" property returns the total free space of the phone? if not I need to know the total free space and then increase the quota of IsolatedStorage. How can I know the actual space free in the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AvailableFreeSpace` is already all free space. On `Windows Phone` you can use all `Isolated Storage` space without increasing quotas